# Difference between socket bind names

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

To create a new INET socket on a particular port, what is the difference between doing the following:

```
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 80))
```

And leaving the bind name empty:

```
serversocket.bind(('', 80))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only matters if your machine has more than one IP address. If you give a specific name, you will bind to whatever IP address that host resolves to. The empty string will bind you to all addresses.

---

Updating.  Actually, I realized the problem is worse than I originally posted. You will have a problem on every machine.

Many people don't realize that `localhost` is a completely different interface than the ip address of the computer.  `localhost` is not just an alias for the machine's IP.

If a server binds to `localhost`, it will only listen to connections from the current machine to `localhost`.  If a server binds to the external IP address of the machine, it will only listen to connections made to that IP address; it won't see connections to `localhost`.  If a server binds to '', which is equivalent to 0.0.0.0, it will listen to both.

On my MacOS, `socket.gethostname()` returns a name which gets resolved to `127.0.0.1`, localhost.  I don't know if this is a MacOS-ism or is true on other OSs.

But typically, either use `localhost` if you're only listening for connections coming from your own machine (testing, a local server) or use `""`.